# How to use gunicorn as django test server

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm having trouble with normal django testserver (it hangs on some REST API I'm writing). However my normal server (gunicorn) has no problem with it.

Therefore I'd like to use gunicorn as my test server but then the second problem comes in:
- It seems gunicorn uses the normal database from settings (mydb) instead of "test_mydb" as the testserver uses.

Does someone know how to tell gunicorn or myapp/wsgi application which DB to use?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you install gunicorn as Django module (i.e. add  `"gunicorn"` to `INSTALLED_APPS`), you can start server by running

```
python manage.py run_guincorn --settings=your_test_settings
```

Comment: Thanks! I just need to setup some initial data and it looks like it will work.